# How can I make Item Name on Datagridview to add +1 if the Item Name is the same or the Barcode is same

Tags: datagridview, addition, rows, selected

I try to make item Qty add to `datagridview`, to be adding +1 when user select the same item twice. E.g., I have  the following columns on `datagridview`: Item Name, Price, Quantity and Total then Textbox for entering the data also Add button on the Form.

My Problem is Instead of adding +1 to Qty where an item name is the same, it is repeating by numbering rows 4, 3, 2, 1 if I add four times ...but i want it to be 4 in one row.

My code and an image of the form are below.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool Found = false;
           if (dataGridViewp.Rows.Count > 1)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewp.Rows)

                {
                    if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value) == textBox8Name.Text && Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value) == textBox9Pri.Text)
                        row.Cells[2].Value = Convert.ToString(1 + Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[2].Value));
                    Found = true;
                }
            }
            if (!Found)

            {
                dataGridViewp.Rows.Add(textBox8Name.Text, textBox9Pri.Text,1);
            }

            else

            {
                dataGridViewp.Rows.Add(textBox8Name.Text, textBox9Pri.Text,1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Image Datagridview]

Comment: **1)** `Found = true;` should be nested in the preceding if-statement; currently you are setting Found to true if rows count is greater than 1. **2)** Your final if-else statement adds a new row whether or not Found is true.  I suspect your else-statement should not be doing this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your respond I have figured it out and is now working.